# OpenCV function to sort contours

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a contour (vector of 4 Points) and I want to categorise these points into Top-Left, Top-Right, Bottom-Right and Bottom-Left. I will always be working with a 4 pointed shape (not necessarily a rectangle though).

Are there any existing OpenCV functions that can do this for me?

If not, are there any existing OpenCV functions that can sum each points `x+y` and give me back the min and max of the 4 sums? This is how I can work out the Top-Left and Bottom-Right points.

Comment: From where did you got the vector of 4 points for the contour ?

Comment: @ZdaR Its from findContours() then approxPolyDP() to simplify it down to 4 points in a contour

Comment: take a look at [this](https://github.com/sturkmen72/OpenCV_3_KNN_Character_Recognition_Cpp/blob/master/GenData.cpp)